# jQuery .append() not working with bootstrap icons

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using jQuery to dynamically insert Bootstrap Glyphicons after the text on buttons. There is an attribute `data-icon` on the `a` element, that supplies the name of the icon that is supposed to be appended to the link text.

```
var icon_n = $("a.btn.download").attr('data-icon');
$("a.btn.download").append(" <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-" + icon_n + "></span>");
```

HTML:

```
<a href="blog/2015/08/jquery-bootstrap-icons.download.html" class="btn btn-primary download" data-icon="download-alt">Download</a>
```

As far as I know, this is supposed to insert the icon after the text. I checked the console, and there are no errors. I also checked the actual element that the icon is supposed to be set on, there is nothing there.
Why isn't this working, and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close the `class` attribute:

```
$("a.btn.download").append(" <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-" + icon_n + "'></span>");
```

You're missing the closing `'` after the concatenated end of the `<span>` element.